# Custom Environment Variables for Kafka Connect via Docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Is there a way to provide custom variables via Docker-Compose that can be referenced within a Kafka Connector config?

I have the following setup in my docker-compose.yml:

```
- "sql_server=1.2.3.4"
- "sql_database=db_name"
- "sql_username=some_user"
- "sql_password=nahman"
- "sql_applicationname=kafka_connect"
```

Here is my .json configuration file:

```
{
  "name": "vwInv_Tran_Amounts",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "src.consumer.interceptor.classes": "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor",
    "tasks.max": 2,
    "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://${sql_server};database=${sql_database};user=${sql_username};password={sql_password};applicationname={sql_applicationname}",
    "query": "SELECT * FROM vwInv_Tran_Amounts",
    "mode": "timestamp",
    "topic.prefix": "inv_tran_amounts",
    "timestamp.column.name": "timestamp",
    "incrementing.column.name": "Inv_Tran_ID"
  }
}
```

I was able to reference the environment variables using this method with Elastic Logstash, but it doesn't appear to work here.

Whenever loading it via curl I receive:

```
The connection string contains a badly formed name or value. for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:sqlserver://${sql_server};database=${sql_database};user=${sql_username};password={sql_password};applicationname={sql_applicationname}\nInvalid value com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection string contains a badly formed name or value.
```

EDIT/////////
I tried prefixing environment varibles like `CONNECT_SQL_SERVER` and that didn't work.

Comment: On second thought, I suppose this really isn't a docker or kafka issue.. as I'm trying to inject the variable into JSON, and then using cURL. Obviously the variable wouldn't be injected there.. back to the drawing board.

Comment: Coming back to this years later, I feel like the trick here anytime a program/service can't reference environment variables, the trick is to add envsubstr and use that to build out the new json file with applied env vars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like you are looking for [Externalizing Kafka Connect secrets](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-297%3A+Externalizing+Secrets+for+Connect+Configurations), but that would require mounting a file, not using env vars.

JSON Connector config files aren't loaded on Docker container startup. I [made this issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/issues/467) to see if this would be possible.

You would have to template out the JSON file externally, then HTTP-POST them to the port exposed by the container.

> Tried prefixing environment varibles like CONNECT_SQL_SERVER

Those values would go into the Kafka Connect Worker properties, not the properties that need to be loaded by a specific connector task.